# Create input of time in reactjs,

Tags: reactjs, input

[image]

I have to create input fields like this and use them in react component. Is there any library to create such . Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you don't require any third party you can simply create select elements with option of 24 hours with AM/PM.

Comment: @Niraj if second date is dependent on first one, how should I do it. Any blog or something you can suggest.

Comment: You need to edit your question first and for the solution it is simple create state in the component with first date and second date and manage those values based on value changed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create dependable date picker you can use below code in your component:

```
const [from, setFrom] = useState("0");
const [to, setTo] = useState("0");
  return(
<select id="from" onChange={t=> setFrom(t)} >
 <option value="0">Select Time</option>
 <option value="12">12 PM</option>
 .
 .
 . 
 <option value="11">11 AM</option>
</select>

{this.state.from != "0" && 
<select id="toDate" onChange={t=> setTo(t)} >
<option value="0">Select Time</option>
 <option value="12">12 PM</option>
 .
 .
 . 
 <option value="11">11 AM</option>
</select>
 }
);
```

I added a condition to check from time is selected then to time visible so that way you can put your condition when from time selected.